# Password protect remove command mongodb

Tags: mongodb, password-protection

Is there any way to password protect mongodb remove command.

One of my junior did the remove of collection by mistake on production environment. So I want to restrict everyone from using remove command.

Comment: Unfortauntely not, they all come under one permission: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite

Comment: You can create your own roles if you have version =>2.6.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/#user-defined-roles

Comment: @KassymDorsel should make that into an answer, would work well

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create custom roles that allow said users only a subset of commands on the database.

For the role to apply to all databases you need to create it on the admin db. Otherwise it is specific for the db it is created on.

For example you could create the following role to allow read/write to documents, but only read to collections and dbs.

```
use admin
db.runCommand({ createRole: "juniorUser",
  privileges: [{
    resource: { db: "", collection: "" },
    actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove", "createCollection", ]
  }],
  roles: [
    role: "read"
  ]
})
```

This creates a new role that inherits from the basic [read](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) role and also adds the five privileges. You can find a list of all privileges available [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/).

Comment: @ShivanandPawar If it helped enough consider accepting the answer.